# Use the cordova-plugin-file-transfer to download a image, not find the image in android device

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

Why i use the cordova-plugin-file-transfer to download a image, i could use the entry.toURL in the image src, the image could display, but i can't find the image in my android devices: the path 'file:///data/data/com.example.hello/cache/123.png' not found

Comment: tried out something like this in the past and faced the same issue. Looks like the phone needs to be rooted to make it work. Checkout this github link for working sample on this - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations

Comment: Thanks you very much, it works, i totally waste some days to figure out what's the problem, but you save my life:)

Comment: have updated the answer. Please accept so that it helps others too. Glad u made it work. Cheers

Comment: If download success, you should re-scan your device storage, because Cordova does not know if the file is downloaded.

so i made a plugin ,

It is a plugin that updates the gallery after downloading.

https://github.com/pouu69/cordova-plugin-gallery-refresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried out something like this in the past and faced the same issue. Looks like the phone needs to be rooted to make it work. Checkout this [github link](https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations) for working sample on this. It downloads file from server using file transfer plugin and saves it in device using file plugin.

Comment: thanks for that sample.Does this sample only provide pdf file?Can I use this for download videos and images and when offline list that videos and images from device